# Run my java app (System Tray) when Windows starts

Tags: java, windows, system, startup, trayicon

I have searched on the net, but I have not found anything for my case.

I have created an application, that shows only in the SystemTray (icon) when you start. I want to run the jar file or the exe automatically when windows starts.

I would like to do this via code or automatically directly from my app. A menu item (for example) that the user could click on that option, if desired. I searched the internet but have not found anything. 
Thank you in advance 
Thank you very much

Only code Java or Bat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can register your application as a system service, set the starttype auto start

Comment: yes i want to set my app to the windows start, but with the code Java. I read that you can do by transferring the jar file in some folder, possible? @dlbtar

Comment: @LorenzoSogliani what I do was release. exe file and register as system service. that is to start your application in C program. must have start and stop function for system call

Comment: can you explain an example? ty

Comment: in VS project, select Files->New->Project->Windows->Windows Service, then write code in OnStart(string[] args) and OnStop() function.The  complexity lies in the start JVM in C language.Recommend that you use the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/), It's convenient to register java application as system service in common OS.

Comment: in Visual Studio and with language c#?

Comment: yes. i think Java Service Wrapper may be more convenient, just need to configure parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps for windows 7

1)Click the Start windows button , click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open.
2) Open the location that contains the item you want to create a shortcut to.

3) Right-click the item, and then click Create Shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.

4) Drag the shortcut into the Startup folder.

The next time you start Windows, the program will run automatically.

I got from this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Notr that you need use .bat file which having cmmand java -jar <jarname>  and this .bat you need use on startup

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm looking for the instructions (source code) to set my java app (generic) that when windows starts, it is executed well. Only java code @prashant thakre

Comment: for example for .bat file?

Comment: just create .bat in your above mentioned startup folder and write  inside the .bat as java -jar fullpath/jarname.jar

Comment: it's ok but how to create file(bat) and move to correct folder(startup folder) into java code? @prashant thakre

Comment: `File file = new File("%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\mine.bat");
      if(!file.exists()){
          file.createNewFile();
      }`

Comment: Thank you so much and then what do i have to write into the file.bat? @prashant thakre And the path that you have pasted into system windows 8 are wrong, right?